# Q: Sum of all maximum numbers in all segments O(N)

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of integers, find sum of all maximum numbers in all segments ( intervals ) in **O(n)**.

Comment: This question is fine, but it needs refinement. Especially, please provide your attempt to solve it, and explain why it isn't good enough.

Comment: Close voters: Please let OP a chance to refine his question before casting close votes less than 2 minutes after it is asked.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For an array of length ``N``  you have to compute ``N * (N+1) / 2`` "max terms" and sum those up. So, at least in a straight forward approach, this is not O(n), I think.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a solution O(N) for this task using stack.

Comment: Is it a code contest question ? Can you provide a link to the contest ?

Comment: That suspense! I kept this question open now for a full day and no one found a good answer. Who can proof or disproof the claim that it is O(N)?

Comment: Suspense is over. There is a `O(n)` solution using a stack.

Comment: @R.Martin If an answer solves your question don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution in O(n)

The C++ source code follows, the program reads either the standard input or a
file whose path is provided as first argument on the command line.

The format of the input file is expected to be:

1. N an integer representing the number of elements in the array
2. N integers separated by spaces representing the elements of the array

Compilation is done through:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -g -Wall -O0    solution.cpp   -o solution
```

The program will first compute the sum using the `O(n)` algorithm then with the
`O(n^3)` algorithm for verification.

Example run:

```
$ ./solution.exe 
3 
4 5 6
O(n) sum: 32
O(n^3) sum: 32
```

Source code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc > 1)
        freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);

    // load input array
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> A(N);
    for(auto& ai : A)
        cin >> ai;

    // compute sum max of all subarrays in O(n)
    vector<int> l(N);
    vector<int> r(N);
    stack<int> s;

    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        while(s.size() && A[s.top()] < A[i]) {
            r[s.top()] = i;
            s.pop();
        }
        s.push(i);
    }
    while(s.size()) {
        r[s.top()] = N;
        s.pop();
    }

    for(int i=N-1; i>=0; --i) {
        while(s.size() && A[s.top()] <= A[i]) {
            l[s.top()] = i;
            s.pop();
        }
        s.push(i);
    }
    while(s.size()) {
        l[s.top()] = -1;
        s.pop();
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        int cs = A[i]*(i-l[i])*(r[i]-i);
        sum += cs;
    }
    cout << "O(n) sum: " << sum << '\n';

    // compute sum using O(n^3) algorithm for verification
    sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        for(int j=i; j<N; ++j) {
            int cs = *max_element(begin(A)+i, begin(A)+j+1);
            sum += cs;
        }
    }
    cout << "O(n^3) sum: " << sum << '\n';
}
```

## Proof of the solution

First, this is not the complete the proof. I have a proof but it is too much
involved in mathematical notation to be included on a site without mathjs
support... I will give the sketch of the proof and let the details to the
reader (I know it's lame).

The solution use multiple *tricks*:

- sum of the max of all sub-arrays is equal to the sum of the product of each
  maximal values by the number of subarrays for which this is the maximal value
- it is possible to partition the set of all sub-arrays into a set of set of
  subarrays. Each set in this partition contains only sub-arrays with the same
  maximal element and the size of the set is easily computed

Let's name the element of the problem:

- The initial array is called: `A`. The value `A[i]` is the value at the 0-based index `i` in the array.
- The size of the array is `n`. The array extends from index `0` to `n-1`.

First, I define what I call the *leader* of a sub-array, this is the index `i`
of an element in the subarray such that the value `A[i]` is maximal for the
sub-array and every elements in the sub-array at an index `j < i` have
`A[j]<A[i]`. Intuitively, the *leader* of a sub-array is the index of its first
maximal value.

I say that equality of *leader* defines an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) on the
sub-arrays. (proof left as an exercise).

From this, we know that the equivalence classes [form a partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Fundamental_theorem_of_equivalence_relations) of the set of
all sub-arrays. In addition all elements from an equivalence class have the
same maximal value (due to the definition of the *leader* function).

The size of an equivalence class `E_i`, the set of all sub-arrays whose *leader*
is `i`, is easily computed from the values:

- `l(i)` which is the first index on the left of `i` where `A[l(i)] >= A[i]` or
  -1 if no such index exists
- `r(i)` wich is the first index on the right of `i` where `A[l(i)] > A[i]` or
  `n` if no such index exists

With these notations the cardinal of `E_i` is: `(i-l(i))*(r(i)-i)`. Proof left as an exercise to the reader.

Now the programming trick to compute the values `l(i)` and `r(i)`. As the
computation is almost the same I will only explain computation of `l(i)`. We
maintain a stak of indexes, with the following invariants:

- indexes in the stack represents *leaders*
- all indexes are in increasing order
- all values associated to indexes in the stack are also in increasing order

We scan from left to right the array. For each index `i` we check if its value
is greater than that of the current top of the stack. If this is the case it means the sub-array whose *leader* is the top of the stack cannot extend past the current index on the right. So we update the value of *r(top of stack)* to be `i`. We pop the top of the stack as it may not be involved in any sub-array extending past `i`.
We continue to update *leaders* and pop the top of the stack until either the
stack is empty or `A[top of stack] >= A[i]`. Then we push `i` on the stack.
When reaching the end of the array there may still be some indexes in the stack.
This means they participate in sub-arrays extending to the end of the array.
We update their `r` value to be `N`.

The whole scan updates all values for `r()` in `O(n)`. This is because each
element is

- updated once
- pushed once

As we cannot pop an element more than once, the inner `while` loop doesn't run
more than `n` times for the whole array scan.

Same process is used to compute `l()` except that:

- we scan backward from right to left
- we use a strict weak comparison because of the definition of *leader*
- we use `-1` to indicate the limit is the bound of the array

Then we can just apply the formula to compute the size of the equivalence
classes and use this in our summation. Leading to an `O(n)` algorithm, as we
need:

- `O(1)` to read `r(i)`
- `O(1)` to read `l(i)`
- `O(1)` to read `A(i)` the maximal value of the sub-arrays in `E_i`

Comment: O(N) confirmed. Compared to my solution, here the timings for different sizes (re-implemented your solution in F#, first time is mine, second is yours): ``N: 1000 -> 1ms, 0ms; N: 10000 -> 88ms 1ms; N = 100000 -> 8908ms 9ms``

Comment: @BitTickler thanks, I wanted to do this benchmark, but I lost too much time due to the lack of latex support that I didn't take time to do it...

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the problem is *not* O(N), because the number of sequences in a data set of length N is `N * (N+1) / 2`, which can be easily shown:

> N = 1: 1 sequence ([1]) -> 1 * 2 / 2 = 1
>
> N = 2: 3 sequences ([1], [2], [1,2]) -> 2 * 3 / 2 = 6 / 2 = 3
>
> N = 3: 6 sequences ([1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3]) -> 3 * 4 / 2 = 12 / 2 = 6

And in order to find the sum of max values of all sequences, all sequences need to be iterated. q.e.d. **update** Or not... see fjardon's answer to admire the power of equivalence classes.

Having said that, you can avoid additional complexity by exploiting the fact that at a position i0, the maximum of a sequence of length w is `max (seq i0 (w-1)) data.[i0+w-1])`.

Which leads to an implementation along the lines of the F# snippet below:

```ml
let maxsum (a: int[]) : int =
    let mutable x = 0
    let mutable total = 0
    let n = Array.length a
    for i0 in 0..n-1 do
        x <- a.[i0]
        total <- total + x
        for w in 2..n-i0 do
            x <- max x a.[i0+w-1]
            total <- total + x
    total
```

Comment: `all sequences need to be iterated` this is not true...

Comment: @fjardon Please elaborate. What you state sounds to me as if someone said: To find the max value in an array, you only need to look at half the array.

Comment: No, I said you only need to look **O(1)** times at all elements. Indeed, can you try to prove your statement that you **must** iterate over all **sequences** ?

Comment: Then show us how it is done in your answer :) I waited for more than a day before I wrote mine, hoping someone would do better.

Comment: I wrote an answer :)