# Iterating through every combination of elements with repetitions without generating whole set

Tags: algorithm, iteration, combinations

I need to iterate over every possible combination of elements (with repetitions) up to n elements long.

I've found multiple solutions for this problem. But all of these are recursively generating collection of every possible combination, then iterating over it. while this works, for large element collections and combinations size it results in heavy memory use, so I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to calculate next combination from previous one, knowing number of elements, and maximum size of combination.

Is this even possible and is there any particular algorith that would work here?

Comment: [Next Permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) are you after a similar behavior to this provided in c++?

Comment: @SamerTufail Unfortunately not. I need to traverse combinations (order of elements does not matter, order of combinations should be predictable but is not really important), so every permutation should be treated as same combination.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve ? Sometimes you do not have to iterate over a set to compute a function over the set. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483058/q-sum-of-all-maximum-numbers-in-all-segments-on) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46521457/657700) for an example.

Comment: @fjardon I have to select few best (by objective function) combinations that satisfy a set of conditions. So it's actually optimization problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the combinations so that each combination is sorted. (This assumes the elements themselves can easily be placed in order. The precise ordering relationship is not important as long as it is a total order.)

Start with the combination consisting of *n* repetitions of the smallest element. To produce the next combination from any given combination:

1. Scan backwards until you find an element which is not the largest element. If you can't find one, you are done.
2. Replace that element and all following elements with the next larger element of that element.

If you want combinations of all lengths up to *n*, run that algorithm for each length up to *n*. Or start with a vector which contains empty slots and use the above algorithm with the understanding that the "next larger element" after an empty slot is the smallest element.

Example: length 3 of 3 values:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 3 3
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 3 3
3 3 3
```

Comment: That's actually approach I wanted to avoid, mostly due to size of collection you need to keep in memory. For example there are 593775 combinations of 6 elements out of 25 elements long set, considering elements are 4byte numbers. it's over 2 MB without any overhead. That's why I'm asking if there is any clever mathematical solution to this.

Comment: @k.kowalczyk: but you don't need to generate them all at once. Generate one, do whatever you need with it, then generate the next one. That's what iterate means. The algorithm tells you how to "generate the next one".

Comment: Right, I misunderstood the answer earlier. That's exactly what I needed, thanks.